# Django form - browser back button functionality

Tags: jquery, html, django

I have a django form with existing id(means, details came from server).

After clicking submit, the submit button becomes 'submitting..' and it will go to new page after submission.

Now, when we click "back" button of browser, it is behaving oddly. Sometimes, the javascript not working properly. Also, submit button became 'submitting..' in firefox.

I want to know the correct way of handling this.

Things in my mind:

1. When edit page is shown because of back button, we catch that event using jquery and set window.location = current url which reloads current page(not refresh) with the previously saved data.
2. Show message that form has expired etc when back button pressed after form submission(I remember some sites using this way).

Along with your opinion on what to do, also please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Could you help us with a code example?

Comment: You're submitting the form by Ajax?

Comment: Mark, no, its not ajax. I am asking about normal form submission. But I need javascript because, for example, I have a link that adds new input fields which is not working sometimes. Even replicating error became difficult. Sometimes not working, sometimes working. But "submitting..." is always visible after clicking back button.

@DirkHorsten I am expecting experts advice. If you need code/demo to understand a common  issue like this, please ignore. Let the experts answer based on their experience with this kind of issue.

Comment: My experience with strange back button behaviour is usually related to caching problems that can be solved with @vary_on_headers. I'm no expert though, so feel free to ignore.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers

Comment: I cant ignore your respectful answer. Thanks a lot for your time. I rejected to provide code here, because that doesnt make sense. One can assume that I didnt follow any special things(like Mark commented on varyonheaders).

Comment: Still, without a (reproducible) code example, answers are going to be full of guesswork. And that makes this a bad question, I'm voting to close it. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve